# How to select category 1 and 6 in LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I need to select 2 different categories from same table using EF with LINQ in C#

Like:

```
 _tour.Products.Where(na => na.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID == 1 && na.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID == 6);
```

this works if I do use != to filer these categories from another list selected from the same table..just not able to select only these two categories. Can anybody help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way for a category to have `ID == 1` **AND** `ID == 6` at the same time. Use **OR** instead:

```
 _tour.Products.Where(na => na.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID == 1 || na.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID == 6);
```

Comment: oh boy, do I fell stupid or what :/ ..thank you, of course it worked :)